# How do i get the list which is sorted <Rich:DataTable> in the backing bean

Tags: datatable

I am showing a list in the  which is sortable. How do i get the sorted list in the backing bean.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to bind the data table. But it is not working. :(